# What is a "RS" in a html(text) file?

Tags: html, text

The file is opened by Everedit. I want know what the "RS" is.

[image: screenshot of the code]

And Notepad++

[image: screenshot2]

I got this page from our school library website. This page shows the result of your query for some book. Some books may be written by more than one author. So the authors column there contains two authors with a little space between them. The page works fine with IE6. But on IE11, Firefox and Chrome the space just vanished. Two authors became one author with a long name. I opened the html file using Notepad.exe and found nothing. Then I opened it with Everedit, I got the "RS" there.

Comment: Well, it looks like the "RS" are characters of content placed within `td` elements in the HTML.  I can't really think of any reason why a `td` element *shouldn't* be allowed to have an "R" or an "S" in its content.  Can you perhaps elaborate on what the problem is?  (Also... IE6?  That's still a thing?)

Comment: I'd guess it's a zero width space or similar. Try showing invisible characters in notepad++

Comment: @David Well, it's not actually content. In IE6 it appears like a space. But in Firefox and chrome it's nothing. I can't even see it. That's why I'm confused. What is it exactly.

Comment: @Anthony In notepad++ it seems more obvious. And I'm more confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like it's a non-printable character, which can often appear very differently in different applications.  (I ran into a problem with these in SQL queries once, where another colleague was using a different editor which copied/pasted things differently.)  It's tough to say with certainty which character it is, but based on [this table](http://www.asciitable.com) (or [this one](http://web.itu.edu.tr/~sgunduz/courses/mikroisl/ascii.html) which separates out the non-printable characters) my best guess is Record Separator:

```
DEC   30
HEX   1E
OCT   036
CHAR  RS
```

If you can examine the character in an octal or hexadecimal editor you can confirm this.  You'd just have to identify the byte to examine (probably by copying that small piece into another file to examine).

If this is the case, then chances are you can *probably* just delete that character in any editor which can see it.  I can't think of a reason why you'd need it in the text, particularly in a browser UI.